# RAW or ACP codepage, which one is best suited?

Tags: sql-server, codepages

I'm trying to automatically import/export some files with special characters (let's say UTF) using bcp utility. However, I can only do it when bulk inserting or exporting with the codepages RAW and ACP.

I have a different educational background, so my question is: For which one should I opt?

From my understanding RAW does not convert any character codes. But I'm not sure what problems it may bring, given that ACP is much more used, so it must be for a reason.

Comment: Can't you just try them both?

Comment: Yeah I tried and saw almost no differences, that's why i'm asking, if in the long run one might show problems or not, since i'm developping a web app

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to avoid character loss due to code page differences is with a Unicode data file because Unicode does not use a code page.  You mention UTF (UTF-8?) which implies that the data are Unicode so you should use a Unicode file.   See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188289.aspx for more information about the Unicode character format.

There is always the potential for character loss when you translate non-Unicode data between code pages.  With varchar/char columns, the source and target column collations must be the same to ensure characters are mapped the same way.  Also, for with non-unicode files, the specified file code page must be the same as the source/target column collations or RAW.  RAW basically implies that the source and target collations of char/varchar columns are the same (and therefore have the same code page).  If the actual collation code pages are different and RAW is specified, characters outside the ASCII range of 0-127 may not translate correctly.

ACP is the same as specifying the widely used code page 1252 so you could have issues if the actual column collation code pages are a different code page.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the -N argument, you can force the bcp to use unicode for certain characters, based on the bcp examination of the data. This uses two bytes per character I think, and should do the job.